# Coddington's An Introduction to Differential Equations, Tenenbaum's Ordinary Differential Equations or Ince's Ordinary Differential Equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, book-recommendation

Which of these books, Coddington's An Introduction to Differential Equations, Tenenbaum's Ordinary Differential Equations and Ince's Ordinary Differential Equations, is better to learn Differential Equations (at least the ordinary differential equations)?

Answer (score 1):

Zill & Wright's book "Differential Equations with Boundary-Value Problems" is pretty good. I'm still using this book in my final year of undergrad studies.

Wish I could attach the textbook here as I have a pdf copy.

Comment: Can you send it via gmail or gdrive? I need it as I am an incoming 3rd year student. Thank you so much. My email is materialslearning57@gmail.com